# Nameserver Setup For Subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, nameserver

I have a domain, flossnet.co.za which is pointing to a VPS at Contabo with nameservers ns1.flossnet.co.za and ns2.flossnet.co.za

I have created a subdomain, courses.flossnet.co.za which points to a VPS at A2 Hosting.

I have added in the web hosting control panel for courses.flossnet.co.za, the nameservers ns1.flossnet.co.za and ns2.flossnet.co.za

However, when checking the nameservers for courses.flossnet.co.za with whatsmydns, it does not show any nameserver.

Any idea how one fixes it?

Edit: zone file for courses.flossnet.co.za

```
; Generated by CWP
; Zone file for courses.flossnet.co.za
$TTL 14400
@    86400        IN      SOA     ns1.flossnet.co.za. postmaster.courses.flossnet.co.za. (
                2023031501 ; serial, todays date+todays
                3600            ; refresh, seconds
                7200            ; retry, seconds
                1209600         ; expire, seconds
                86400 )         ; minimum, seconds
@   86400   IN  NS      ns1.flossnet.co.za.
@   86400   IN  NS      ns2.flossnet.co.za.
@ IN A 190.92.190.225
localhost.courses.flossnet.co.za. IN A 127.0.0.1
@ IN MX 0 courses.flossnet.co.za.
mail 14400 IN CNAME courses.flossnet.co.za.
smtp 14400 IN CNAME courses.flossnet.co.za.
pop  14400 IN CNAME courses.flossnet.co.za.
pop3 14400 IN CNAME courses.flossnet.co.za.
imap 14400 IN CNAME courses.flossnet.co.za.
webmail 14400 IN A 190.92.190.225
cpanel 14400 IN A 190.92.190.225
cwp 14400 IN A 190.92.190.225
www 14400 IN CNAME courses.flossnet.co.za.
ftp 14400 IN CNAME courses.flossnet.co.za.
_dmarc  14400   IN  TXT "v=DMARC1; p=none"
@   14400   IN  TXT "v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:190.92.190.225 ~all"
default._domainkey 14400 IN TXT "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC9p/voIvEPAgp+ECehUdGkiBDIEAXhjbg+fddN+4te7XwLhkLaQK8AWJ4x5y6iwsTnDTO2VY4jkIFLpQFxfjBuj4vk/vVKOD7GGowvJBySBjTrNS9gWs8p8EoM5Hi+o0SZJQ1Sd3wAq2DDMRTujXGEXukBb/UqYGoRfx9mV1FMEwIDAQAB"
courses IN NS ns1.courses; Delegation record
ns1.courses IN A 190.92.190.225; Glue record
```

Comment: Tell us the real names so we can check. Don't hide DNS names when you ask about DNS.

Comment: +100 to @vidarlo comment and also just ask your "provider A" and "provider B" for help if you can't set up things correctly. The best online troubleshooting tool to use if you want to do it yourself (which you have to until you disclose real names involved) is DNSViz. Fix any errors it reports.

Comment: @vidarlo, I have rephrased the question.

Comment: Your server doesn't return any NS records. Show your zone file.

Answer (score 2):

> I have created a subdomain, courses.flossnet.co.za which points to a VPS at A2 Hosting.

Yes, you have created a A record that points to `190.92.190.225`. That doesn't do *anything* but create an A-record.

If you want to hand control of `courses.flossnet.co.za` to another nameserver, you have to create a NS record to provide a delegation:

```
courses IN NS ns1.courses; Delegation record
ns1.courses IN A 190.92.190.225; Glue record
```

This way you delegate control of `courses.flozznet.co.za` to `ns1.courses.flozznet.co.za` and provide an IP for this.

These records has to be created in the `flozznet.co.za` zone.

You would then of course have to configure the namserver running on you VPS accordingly.

Note that delegation is only required if you want `ns1` in this example to be able to add names on its own.

Comment: @vidario, I have added the zone file for courses.flossnet.co.za.db above.

Comment: Those two records should go into the `flossnet.co.za` zone.